# how to get keys and values from a Map(obj) in a loop (js)?

Tags: javascript

I try to get the key and values out of a map in a loop, in the second run the key and value is undefined. any ideas?

```js
let map = new Map();
map.set('{{NAME}}', 'Name');
map.set('{{CLASS}}', 'Sorc');

let keyIterator = map.keys();
let valIterator = map.values();
let counter = map.size;

for (let i = 0; i < counter; i++){
  console.log('Key: ' + keyIterator.next().value);
  console.log('Val: ' + valIterator.next().value);
}
```

Output:

Key: {{NAME}}

Val: Name

Key: undefined

Val: undefined

I hope its not a duplicate, but i couldnt find an clear answer to my problem.

Comment: This works for me, the output is as expected

Comment: well, this snippet i posted runs with the expected output.. then my error is somewhere different. sorry guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate the entries of map by using a `for ... of` statement.

```js
let map = new Map();
map.set('{{NAME}}', 'Name');
map.set('{{CLASS}}', 'Sorc');


for (let [k, v] of map) {
    console.log('Key: ' + k);
    console.log('Val: ' + v);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your solution, i use this now and all works like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

Make it simple and just use the method of `forEach` from Map object.

```js
let map = new Map();
map.set('{{NAME}}', 'Name');
map.set('{{CLASS}}', 'Sorc');

map.forEach((val,key) => {
  console.log(`Key: ${key}`)
  console.log(`Val: ${val}`)
})
```

Comment: look at it now, got a bit confused with what you needed

Comment: thanks, works well too. i just need to replace variables from a json file with the value of the keys in the map. now it works, saved your solution! Thank you!

Comment: Happy it helped, please mark it as approved for others to benefit